# In python sympy, how do I apply an external python funtion to each element of the sympy matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

To be more specific, I want to apply the following sigmoid function:

```
def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + m.exp(-x))
```

to each element of the following 2x2 Sympy Matrix:

```
Matrix([[1,3],[2,4]])
Matrix([
[1, 3],
[2, 4]])
```

Such that on applying the sigmoid function onto the matrix I'll get a new  2x2 Matrix where each individual element of the Matrix had the sigmoid applied to it. Like the following :

```
Matrix([[ sigmoid(1), sigmoid(3) ],[ sigmoid(2), sigmoid(4) ]])
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> M.applyfunc(sigmoid)

Matrix([
[1/(exp(-1) + 1), 1/(exp(-3) + 1)],
[1/(exp(-2) + 1), 1/(exp(-4) + 1)]])
```

This is using SymPy's `exp` in the `sigmoid` function. If `m.exp` means you are importing `exp` from `math`, then the result won't look nice, and will error out if the matrix contains symbols.

---

If you literally want `sigmoid(1)` and so on inside the function, then `sigmoid` needs to be a SymPy function that does not evaluate anything.

```
class sigmoid(Function):
    pass
```

With this,

```
>>> M.applyfunc(sigmoid)
Matrix([
[sigmoid(1), sigmoid(3)],
[sigmoid(2), sigmoid(4)]])
```